# C# XmlTextWriter can't write to file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with the XmlTextWriter class, I can't write to a file.

It is a console application I'm creating and the function looks like this.

```
private void WriteXML()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Writing");
        using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("DataW.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteComment("This is a comment");
            writer.WriteStartElement("WeeklyReview");

            writer.WriteStartElement("DateTime");
            writer.WriteStartAttribute("DateTime","09/04/2018 05:00");
            writer.WriteElementString("Activity", "At Theodor");
            writer.WriteElementString("Social", "Not Theodor,Theodor");
        }
    }
```

The result I'm getting is just a file with nothing in it. And in VS 2017 the file is shown with a white background and nothing in it.

The file I'm writing to is in the solution explorer and located in the same place as the file I'm reading from (which works).

Comment: What does `I can't write to a file` mean, specifically?

Comment: If you're getting an error, telling us what it is would be very helpful.

Comment: @SamAxe thx, I have now updated the title

Comment: @Amy if only I got an error, but it runs with no errors

Comment: Please refrain from adding "Solved" to the questions title.  See [this Meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question) to understand why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue you're seeing is that the XML file created is blank or incomplete.  If so, add a `using` statement around your code like so:

```
using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("DataW.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteComment("This is a comment");
    writer.WriteStartElement("Weekly Review"); //NB: A space in an element name!

    writer.WriteStartElement("DateTime");
    writer.WriteStartAttribute("09/04/2018 05:00"); //NB: a value given as an attribute name (consider: WriteAttributeString)!
    writer.WriteElementString("Activity", "At Theodor");
    writer.WriteElementString("Social", "Not Theodor,Theodor");
}
```

The reason for the issue is the methods you're calling write to an underlying stream rather than to the file system.  To ensure that data is written to the file system you need to call the `Flush` method.  Flush is called automatically when the writer is closed/disposed (but not when it's finalized).  The `using` statement ensures that your `writer` is always disposed of correctly, so will ensure that your stream is flushed to disk.

For any other issues, you'd likely have an exception thrown (e.g. were there file access issues writing to the target location).  If you're receiving an exception, please share that message and we can recommend a solution for that.

---

ps. The XML created by this is given below / it's not valid XML, so you'll have other issues down the line.  I'll leave those for you to resolve, or for you to ask as another question should you have issues there.  In the meantime, you can get some hints from the example in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter.writestartattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This is a comment-->
<Weekly Review>
  <DateTime 09/04/2018 05:00="">
    <Activity>At Theodor</Activity>
    <Social>Not Theodor,Theodor</Social>
  </DateTime>
</Weekly Review>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with your suggested code, but I still can't write successfully to the file. And I get no errors.
Yea I know my xml is not the greatest, but just getting started :)

Comment: Try sticking `Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath("DataW.xml"));` on the end of your code / see what path it gives you... I have a feeling you may be looking at a file from a previous test, rather than the file that's currently being created. Most likely under the solution's `\Debug\bin` directory.   Alternatively, use a full file path (e.g. `@"c:\test\DataW.xml"` or `"c:\\test\\DataW.xml"`) to ensure the file's being written where you expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you, that was the case. It was writing to \Debug\bin.

Answer (score 1):

I know the Question is old, but in VB.net i got the same result.

I had to call `XmlTextWriter.Flush()` at the End to get Content in my File.